# Python threading in flask webapp

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I've been trying threads recently in my webapp, and I've come across an issue that I cannot seem to solve.

The issue is that I have an index page, and every time the user enters that page, a **new** thread is being started which checks for changes in my database in a while loop, although I only want **one** thread to be on at that moment. Is there a way to "kill" a thread when the index page is accessed the second time and then start a new one?

I did try to use `is_alive()` to check if a thread is already running, but had no success since all the time they're different.

Code example below:

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():

    @copy_current_request_context
    def check_for_updates():
        while True:
            ...... # Query for information

            if something_changed:
                socketio.emit('new_notifications', {'data': new_data})
            if index_opened_again:
                break
            sleep(5)

    index_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_for_updates, daemon=True)

    index_thread.start()
    
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

I user the below code to kill threads when I am existing a server ,
My suggestion is to kill all active threadss before opening a new one

```
for id, thread in threading._active.items():          
      ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
```

Answer (score 1):

In my example I use a global variable in combination with a lock. It's certainly not optimal, but you can check if a thread is already running.
If you're using flask-socketio anyway, I recommend you take a look at [`start_background_task`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#socketio.Client.start_background_task). The functionality is compatible with that of a standard thread.

```
from threading import Lock
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'
sio = SocketIO(app)

thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()

def background_task():
    while True:
        # ... 
        sleep(5)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  global thread
  with thread_lock:
      if thread is None:
          thread = sio.start_background_task(background_task)
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

Comment: Right, thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. But what exactly is the `thread_lock` used here for? Never really understood the `lock()` feature of threads

Comment: @Redas A lock guarantees that access to the respective area is blocked. Further access must wait until the lock has been lifted. With multiple threads, it can thus be ensured that the state of a variable within the area cannot be changed from outside during access.